# C# MVC net.7 Application goes in time out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, timeout

I have created a web application in C# MVC net.7 that run on IIS windows server 2019
The program works well but after 30 mins the application times out.

In the Program.cs file I have tried the following:

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(14);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

When I tried it in debug it works well, but when I publish it still times out after 30 mins.

Any ideas?
TY

Comment: Is this deployed to aws, azure, iis?

Comment: IIS on windows server 2019 i forgot to specify sorry

Comment: Then you need to set the app pool idle timeout setting. You can do this in IIS, or through your web config. The default is 20 mins.

Comment: What you mean about time out? After 30 minutes, when you make a new request to the application, it shows time out error? How about the next request? Still facing the same error?

Comment: After 30 minutes when i when i change page or click some button i will automatically return to the log in page.What i have to write into the web config to change the pool idle timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you store the user credential? Inside the cookie or session?  Which authentication schema you have used? According to your description, it seesm the user credential expire which caused your application login again.

If you just want to know how to modify the IIS application pool idle time, you could refer to below steps:

Details, you could refer to below image:

1.Locate the application pool:

[image]

2.Modify the advanced settings.

[image]